# Equality of annihilators of a vector space implies equality of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem as follows: $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Let $W^0_i$ be the annihilator of $W_i$ for $i = 1,2$.

Prove that $W^0_1=W^0_2 \implies W_1=W_2$.

Comment: Is $W_{0}$ the annihilator in the dual space of $V$ or is it the annihilator with respect to some inner product or bilinear form? Your question needs some clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $W_1\neq W_2$, then choose $v\in W_1\setminus W_2$ (or the other way around), and extend $\{v\}$ to a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$. Now define $f:V \to k$ by
$$
f(v) = 1 \text{ and } f(w) = 0 \quad\forall w\in \mathcal{B}\setminus \{v\}
$$
extended linearly. Then note that $f \in W_2^0\setminus W_1^0$

Comment: Can you explain what is lowercase $k$?

Comment: @mgus: The ground field

Comment: This is also true if V is not finite-dimensional.